# How can I view a Google document that says "File will be deleted soon"?

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to view this Google document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-KxI1oZl9A0DMewZBJArUPPKUrVLYr4FrDey5d_3QR0/edit

When I open the Google document, it says

> File will be deleted soon
> This file might be deleted soon. If you still need access, sign in to make a copy, download the file, or request access from the owner.

How can I view the Google document without having to sign in?

[image]

Comment: Weird. I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

The message is because the document has been placed in the owner's trash, and the trash has not been emptied yet. Once the trash is emptied it will not be available at all. How long that takes is individual. How often do you empty the "trash" on your desktop, for example?

To view the file you *must*, as Google instructed:
 * Sign in and make a copy, which will land in your documents,
 * Download the file to you computer (Google Docs Menu *File* -> Download), or
 * Contact the owner and request access.

Downloading does not require that you sign in. Then you can view/edit the file locally.

**Note**: Once the owner cleans out their trash, even that option will be gone.